# Add two numbers stored in reverse order in linked lists

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in forward order, and each of their nodes contains a single digit. Add the two numbers and return the sum as a linked list.
You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.

```
Example:
2 --> 4 --> 3
5 --> 6 --> 4
8 --> 0 --> 7

Input: l1 = [2,4,3], l2 = [5,6,4]
Output: [8,0,7]
Explanation: 243 + 564 = 807
```

The linked list is a collection of ListNode objects where each object points to the next one.
The ListNode class is the following:

```
// Definition for singly-linked list.
public class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode() {}
    ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
    ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
}
```

I've tried the follwing solution with a recursive approach

```
import java.util.HashMap;

class Solution {
    public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        ListNode head = new ListNode(0);
        head.val = generateSumList(l1.next, l2.next, head.next);
        return head;
    }


    public int generateSumList(ListNode l1, ListNode l2, ListNode res) {
        
        int rest, sum;

        if (l1.next == null && l2.next != null) {
            return generateSumList(l1, l2.next, res.next);
        }

        if (l1.next != null && l1.next == null) {
            return generateSumList(l1.next, l2, res.next);
        }

        if (l1.next == null && l2.next == null) {
            sum = l1.val + l2.val;
            if (sum > 9) {
                ListNode n = new ListNode(sum % 10, null);
                res = n;
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                ListNode n = new ListNode(sum, null);
                res = n;
                return 0;
            }
        }

        rest = generateSumList(l1.next, l2.next, res.next);
        sum = l1.val + l2.val + rest;
        if (sum > 9) {
            res.val = sum % 10;
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            res.val = sum;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having the follwing error msg at runtime and I cannot understand why.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "next" because "<parameter1>" is null
  at line 27, Solution.generateSumList
  at line 17, Solution.addTwoNumbers
  at line 54, __DriverSolution__.__helper__
  at line 87, __Driver__.main
```

Why am I having the NPE? Are my approach to the problem and my intuition on how to solve it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why am I having the NPE?

The node you assign to `head` has a `next` member that is `null`. This `null` is passed as last argument to `generateSumList`, so that `res` is `null`. When neither `l1.next` nor `l2.next` is `null` the following line is executed and produces the NPE as it evaluates `res.next`:

```
    rest = generateSumList(l1.next, l2.next, res.next);
```

> Are my approach to the problem and my intuition on how to solve it correct?

No, it cannot work like that. For one, if the two lists have an unequal length, you cannot hope to align the two corresponding digits from both lists. Although you get the *last* two digits aligned and added together, eventually, `sum = l1.val + l2.val + rest;` will get executed, but those two nodes are equally positioned when counting from the *left*, but should be aligned by their distance from the *right*. In short, when the lists have an unequal length, this `sum` is summing up unrelated digits.

To achieve a correct alignment of the nodes, you would better first reverse both lists, so the least significant digits come first, and are naturally aligned as you move forward.

Comment: Thank you for the answer it was crystal clear